# Upsample with Verilog

Tags: verilog

I need to upsample(2x) my data using Verilog. I think to use three ports for input and one port for output. Input ports are filterin, reset and clock. Output port is filterout. Also I need dynamic input size. How can I realize this with Verilog.

Edit1:
My input and output datas are 16 bit long. I just need a Verilog code to do this:

If Input: 1 2 3,
Then Output: 1 0 2 0 3 0.

If Input: 1 2 3 4 5,
Then Output: 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0.

Edit2:
I created a verilog file to solve this but it didn't solve my problem.

### US1.v file

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module US1 (filterin,clk,filterinus);

    input [15:0] filterin;
    input clk;

    output reg [15:0] filterinus;

    integer i=0;

    always @ (posedge clk) begin
        if (i==0) begin
            filterinus <= filterin;
        end
        else begin
            filterinus <= 0;
        end
        i=~i;
    end


endmodule
```

I tested this code with the following Test bench:

### Test.v file

```
`timescale 1ps/1ps
module Test;

    reg [15:0] filterin;
    reg clk;
    wire [15:0] filterinus;

    US1 uut (
        .filterin(filterin), 
        .clk(clk),
        .filterinus(filterinus)
    );

    initial begin
        clk = 1;

        filterin = 1;
        #2 filterin = 2;
        #2 filterin = 3;
        #2 filterin = 4;
        #2 filterin = 5;

        #30 $finish;
    end

    always #1 clk = ~clk;

endmodule
```

As is seen, my input is: 1 2 3 4 5. 
My output is: 1 0 3 0 5 0 5 0 5 0...
I need to see: 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 0 0 0 0...

Comment: You'll need to provide many more details.

Comment: The more context you can provide, the better. What you describe produces 2x as much data on the output as it receives on the input, which implies some kind of flow control. What is this module going to connect to (e.g. other functional blocks, DAC, ADC, memory I/F)? Post the code you have so far.

Comment: I edited my post again and posted my functionless code so far. I need to use dynamic number of Flip-Flops to save and use my past datas.

Comment: In a question like this, most readers will assume that the testbench is specifying design requirements. If the solution is to change the testbench, that suggests the problem wasn't well defined at the start.

Comment: I needed an answer to overcome the upsampling problem. I solved it with changing testbench. With the new testbench, I have a different clock which allows me to see unseen values and is not **just** design requirement. Also I think I defined my problem comprehensible at first. My definition is easy enough to mention the problem which I solved easily as follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I changed filterin input period from my testbench like this:

```
    filterin = 1;
    #4 filterin = 2;
    #4 filterin = 3;
    #4 filterin = 4;
    #4 filterin = 5;
    #4 filterin = 0;
```

And I got my output: 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 0 0...

Answer (score 1):

A few comments on your code, assuming this is for synthesis.

- Don't initialize the variable 'i' in a declaration. This is not always synthesizable.
- Don't use an integer type for a single toggle bit. This makes your code less clear and makes the tools work harder.
- Never mix blocking and non-blocking assignments in the same always block.

Given your description, I'm not sure what operation you're trying to implement here. You said upsampling but this isn't a typical approach such as linear or cubic interpolation methods.